# Android content-provider conflict between Kit Kat and all later versions, 5.x, 6.x and 7.x

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-xml

I'm having a problem with a content provider used for shared log in across 2 different apps. the main trouble is with the `<provider>` tag. If I place it outside the `<application>` tag, the shared resource is seen locally only for both applications and can not share the log in; but runs in Kit Kat. if I place it inside the `<application>` tag it works great for Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat, but crashes on Application Launch in both apps when run in Kit Kat, saying that *the provider class is not defined* in the namespace for that app doesn't exist, but of course it's in the project in the correct namespace. Unfortunately I have to support Kit Kat, and the provider works in 5.x, 6.x and 7.x when the `<provider>` is inside the `<application>` I can share the log in token (JWT) across the apps, which is a requirement for these applications. **How can I get the provider to work in Kit Kat the same as it does in Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat?**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the manifest of the app with the `<provider>` element inside of `<application>` (where it belongs), the code that triggers the crash, and the complete Java stack trace of the crash itself.

Answer (score 1):

> If I place it outside the `<application>`

However your question is not complete as it shows no content of your manifests, I post this as answer for one simple reason: `<provider>` cannot be outside of `<application>`:

```
<provider>
    CONTAINED IN:
       <application>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

therefore it is high chance you are simply using side effect of platform bug that was fixed in later releases.

> I'm having a problem with a content provider used for shared log in across 2 different apps

There're clear mechanisms that would allow you to restrict access to **properly** exposed provider. There's no reason to use tricks, like `android:permission` or optionally `android:grantUriPermissions`. In my opinion you current approach is faulty by design, and that should be fixed in first place.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was a Kit Kat platform bug. "Across two applications;" we have user groups that use 2 applications for 2 differing business reqs. We want to use a shared log in when authenticated on 1 device. We use a shared library. I was kind of constrained by my superiors about releasing details. I am thinking it may be design, the provider class is in the library, I am moving it out of the shared library, repeating it in the projects. You may be correct assuming it's a design flaw; If it works. Odd that the "flaw" in Kit Kat wasn't really documented. Thanks for commenting.